# Why is this SQL script failing?

Tags: sql, scripting, full-text-search

I'm trying to run a SQL script against SQL Server 2005 as part of the set up for my integration tests. The script works perfectly fine if I execute it from within SQL Server Management Studio. However, when executing programmatically, this part of the script that enables full-text search refuses to work:

```
-- lots of tables and indexes created above

create unique nonclustered index [IX_Id] on [MyTable] ( [Id] asc )

-- this line fails
sp_fulltext_database enable
create fulltext catalog MyCatalog with accent_sensitivity = off as default
create fulltext index on MyTable([Title],[Content]) key index IX_Id with change_tracking auto
```

The error I get is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'enable'.

If I remove the lines related to full text, everything works fine. If I change the `sp_fulltext_database enable` call to this:

```
EXEC ('sp_fulltext_database enable');
```

I get a different error:

> Cannot use full-text search in master,
>   tempdb, or model database.

This makes no sense to me at all. The correct database *is* in use.

For reference, the code that executes the script looks like this (I'm using NHibernate):

```
private static void InitializeDatabase()
{
    var sessionFactory = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();

    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        session.CreateSQLQuery("IF DB_ID('" + databaseName + @"') IS NOT NULL DROP DATABASE """ + databaseName + @""";").ExecuteUpdate();
        session.CreateSQLQuery(@"CREATE DATABASE """ + databaseName + @""";").ExecuteUpdate();
        session.CreateSQLQuery(@"USE """ + databaseName + @""";").ExecuteUpdate();
        session.CreateSQLQuery(GetCreationScript()).ExecuteUpdate();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
```

It's a string parameter, not a reserved word.

**EDIT BY KENT:** I marked as answer to give Quassnoi the rep. But to elaborate, if I add my `USE database` statement to the top of my script, it works. For reasons I don't understand, it doesn't work when I execute the `USE database` as a separate statement inside the same session (see my original code).

Comment: Nope - same problem. Cannot use full-text search in master, tempdb, or model database.

Comment: Then you are using `master`, `tempdb` or `model`. Could you please run the script in the `SSMS` (making sure that correct database is selected in the combo box in the upper left corner) and check if the problem persists?

Comment: Cheers Quassnoi - that was driving me insane.